# Create file and upload to existing zip file S3

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, angular7, angular2-services

I have a requirement as below, please suggest if this is possible

1. Create a .py file
2. zip the #1 file to a existing zipfile in S3

I have google and found solutions like filesaver which saves file locally, some other libraries which saves the uploaded file, but in my case i have create  a file and zip inside a existing file in S3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to "modify" an object in Amazon S3.

Therefore, you code would need to:

- **Download** the existing zip file
- **Add** the new file to the zip file
- **Upload** the resulting file to Amazon S3